# Swing JSplitPane problem

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

How to Split Component vertically  into different parts? Is It possible in Swing?
I want to assign different ScrollBar to each part ?

Comment: if you mean splitting an arbitrary component: no, that's not possible (how should it?) And what does a ScrollBar has to do with it? Consider to re-phrase your question, giving more information of _what_ you want to achieve (vs. how you think you can achieve it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the [JSplitPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html)

if you need each part to be on a diffrent scroller - just put them on to diffrent scroller pane.

```
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
            JScrollPane topScrollPane = new JScrollPane(topPanel);

            JPanel buttomPanel = new JPanel();
            JScrollPane buttomScrollPane = new JScrollPane(buttomPanel);

            JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, topScrollPane, buttomScrollPane);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [JSplitPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html). Then put a [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) into each side.

If you want more than one split, you'd have to nest the split panes.
Or use a multi-splitpane like this: [MultiSplitPane](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/23/multi-split-pane.html)

Comment: JXMultiSplitPane is now part of SwingX