# Jcomponent divison

Tags: swing

I want divide jcomponent into different parts

```
public TaskGraphComponent(ProjectFrame proFrame,TaskGraphModel    model,TaskGraphPainter    painter) {
    this.proFrame = proFrame;
    _painter = painter;

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     setModel(model);



  _mouseHandler = new GraphMouseHandler(this);
   _verticalScroll1 = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
  this.add(_verticalScroll1, BorderLayout.EAST);
  _verticalScroll1.addAdjustmentListener(this);
  _verticalScroll1.setVisible(true);    


   setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,15,0));
    this.addMouseMotionListener(_mouseHandler);
    this.addMouseListener(_mouseHandler);
    this.addMouseWheelListener(_mouseHandler);
    this.addKeyListener(_mouseHandler);
    this.addComponentListener(this);
    this.setFocusable(false);
    this.setSize(10, 50);
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(8000);
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setReshowDelay(3000);
}
```

Here TaskGraphComponent is jcomponent can i make into differnt parts  vertically 
TaskGraphComponent is jcomponent uses Borderlayout.TaskgraphComponent wil show big
screen . Actually task is i want to spilt this taskGraphComponent into parts

Comment: Few remarks: you should simplify the example and remove irrelevant code. Moreover, the question is unclear. What should be split and what should be in the two parts? Please edit the question.

Comment: still don't understand what you want, not even in combination with your other question you didn't bother to clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159817/swing-jsplitpane-problem

Answer (score 0):

layout managers?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html